# Route skips view and calls method straight away

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am still new to rails and running into a rather weird problem (at least from my perspective):
There is a view with a form and a route and a method in a controller. Somehow the method gets called straight away instead of rendering the view, waiting for input and the passing that on to the method.

This is what it kinda looks like:

Controller

```
class Some::ThisController < ApplicationController

  def method_a
    variable_a = params[:variable_a].to_time
    variable_b = #other stuff
    @variable_c = # do stuff with the variable_a & variable_b

  end
```

View (method_a.rb)

```
= form_tag this_method_a_path do
  = text_field_tag :variable_a
  = text_field_tag :variable_a
  = submit_tag 'Apply'
```

Routes (some.rb)

```
The::Application.routes.draw do

  namespace :some do

    # leave all the unimportant stuff

    match this/method_a => this#method_a, :as => :method_a
```

So what is my issue?
The view is not being rendered - I only get:
undefined method `to_time' for nil:NilClass
When I rename the method the view renders fine.

What do I want?
The view to render, so I can fill out the form and submit it and then have the method return whatever is in @variable_c.

I cant figure out what goes wrong. Maybe it is too late today...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two separate controller methods, one to render the view and one to accept the submission of the form. `params[:variable_a]` will be unavailable when you're in method_a because the form hasn't been submitted yet, it's just being rendered!

Try this:

```
class Some::ThisController < ApplicationController

  def method_a
    # nothing, just let Rails render the method_a view
  end

  # this will accept the submission of the form 
  def method_b
    variable_a = params[:variable_a].to_time # this will now be available because the user has submitted the form
    variable_b = #other stuff
    @variable_c = # do stuff with the variable_a & variable_b
```

Add the new method to the routes:

```
The::Application.routes.draw do

  namespace :some do

    # leave all the unimportant stuff

    get 'some/method_a' => 'some#method_a', :as => :method_a
    post 'some/method_b' => 'some@method_b'. :as => :method_b
```

And now your view will be:

```
= form_tag method_b_path do 
  = text_field_tag :variable_a
  = text_field_tag :variable_b
  = submit_tag 'Apply'
```

When the user hits the submit button the params `:variable_a` and `:variable_b` will be POSTed to the method_b action in your controller and you will be able to call `params[:variable_a]` or b.

If you don't understand how this works maybe this will help:

- User visits the path `GET /some/method_a` and your app receives the request at the method_a action in your controller and responds by rendering the `method_a.html.erb` view.
- The form is rendered and the user fill out the form and clicks submit sending a **new** request to the method_b action in your controller. Along with this request the params from the `text_fields` are included and you can then use the for your computations.

[Hope that's clear enough.](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/)

Comment: I knew it was something like that! Thanks.

Just out of curiosity since it seems to be working for other people. Is there any way to do that in the method itself?

Comment: It wouldn't be good practice but yea, you'd have to have an if condition checking for the presence of the params first though. Your route would just have to be `match` though so that it can accept any HTTP verb.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this much depends on how you call your route.

Is it a get request? A url-defined "variable_a"? In this case, you are not defining it in you route, so it goes to null...

Or is it a post/patch request? In which case you would most probably have a form posting to a route and hence to a controller method... But you need first to render the form.

So, what you should have is:

A method in your controller to call your form view as 'get'

In your case, as simple as adding in your routes:

```
match "this/method_a", to: "controller#draw_form", via: 'get'
```

In your controller

```
def draw_form
   render "method_a"
end
```

and then, when your form posts to the same url ("this/method_a" in your routes), there will be parameters to be processed by your `method_a` action in your controller.